# How to copy images from a remote server to a local machine in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple way to copy images from a remote server to a local folder using Python. Remote images can be accessed via HTTP.

Comment: Can you please share your existing code? In particular, a *[mcve]* would help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done using numerous ways. I prefer using `request` module as u mentioned that images are accessible over http.

```
import requests
img = open('ur_file_name.jpg', 'wb')
img.write(requests.get('http://url_of_image_in_remote_server.jpg').content)
img.close()
```

This will save the image in current working directory (cwd). If u wish to save images in folder other than cwd then refer to the python's `os.path` documentation.

PS: If the number of images are very high and u r hitting someone elses server, which u dont own, then its advisable to not flood the server with too many requests in short span of time. Its not encouraged (at least I don't).

Comment: In the last line, change the 'f.close()' to 'img.close()'. 

Thanks. Otherwise, it worked.

Comment: Oh! sry for that. bad habit of using 'f' for such operations . Never mind. Edited the answer :) . Thanks for the correction.